# Setting width and height before page renders to remove jerk effect in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have written jquery function which calculates width and height of some of the DOM components in my page based on screen resolution (using `$(window).height() and $(window).width()`).

It is working fine in Mozilla and Firefox, but in Chrome it creates a jerk while loading the screen.

So my question is, is it possible to call my javascript function before page gets rendered on screen?

My goal is to remove the jerk effect.

Thanks.

Comment: if you do not place it in `$(document).ready(function(){});`, and apply the code in the head of your page, it should load before the other elements are all loaded. Some html/js code that you use might be useful as we can take a look at what you got atm.

Comment: Are you scripts in bottom of the page or in top?